# Open New Figure Window from Existing GUI Matlab

Tags: matlab

Please, I have created this sample GUI. I want to be able to open a new GUI from the old one that contains the same information just like in MSWord where the Submenu 'New' always opens a new MSWord document. I don't know if my effort is really the answer since it opens a new figure alright but for a big code, will I always copy and paste? Please is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

```
function []=workmenu()
f=figure('MenuBar','None');
mh=uimenu(f,'Label','File');
mh1=uimenu(f,'Label','Edit');

mh_chd1=uimenu(mh,'Label','New'); %Submenu of mh
set(mh_chd1,'callback',{@newopen}); %Callback for mh_chd1

%Create pop up menu
pp=uicontrol(f,'Style','popupmenu','string',{'One';'Two';'Three'},...
'pos',[30 250 130 20]);

function []=newopen(varargin)
f=figure('MenuBar','None');
mh=uimenu(f,'Label','File');
mh1=uimenu(f,'Label','Edit');

mh_chd1=uimenu(mh,'Label','New'); %Submenu of mh
set(mh_chd1,'callback',{@newopen}); %Callback for mh_chd1

%Create pop up menu
pp=uicontrol(f,'Style','popupmenu','string',{'One';'Two';'Three'},...
'pos',[30 250 130 20]);
end

end
```

Comment: I think you should refine your question. For one working code is always good. But I think you didn't address the fundamental issues - how will you manage the data and functions in two different windows? For that aspect you would really benefit moving to object oriented programming. Also IMHO Matlab is a bad choice for GUI applications - it makes for poorly responding applications (mostly because it's single threaded).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm confused. Why is IMHO a bad choice for gui applications?

Comment: personally it's all about this single thread thing. You have no feedback or control over the app till it gives back control to the user. That's easy to do once you can have several threads.

Comment: So is it that after opening the new Window, one cannot work with it like the main gui Window? Thanks.

Comment: well yes and no - to stay with your word example - usually you don't want every word window to show the same document.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I found out. It still opens a new figure alright.

```
function []=workmenu()
f=figure('MenuBar','None');
mh=uimenu(f,'Label','File');
mh1=uimenu(f,'Label','Edit');

mh_chd1=uimenu(mh,'Label','New'); %Submenu of mh
set(mh_chd1,'callback',{@newopen}); %Callback for mh_chd1

%Create pop up menu
pp=uicontrol(f,'Style','popupmenu','string',{'One';'Two';'Three'},...
'pos',[30 250 130 20]);

function []=newopen(varargin)
    workmenu
end

end
```